# Как интепретировать значение функции потерь после predict?

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Обучил модель и по критерию negative log likelihood получил значение:

```
loss = criterion.forward(pred, y_test)
print(loss)
# loss = 0.09417543244830048
```

О чем говорит данное значение `loss`?

Answer (score 1):

Данное число - значение функции потерь на текущем шаге (эпохе) для текущего "батча".

Само по себе это число говорит нам не много. При обучении модель старается минимизировать функцию потери и соответственно нам интересно наблюдать за данным числом в процессе обучения. Если значение функции потери в процессе обучения уменьшается - значит модель обучается и сходится.

Часто в процессе обучения значение функции потери начинает возрастать после того как оно уменьшалось на предыдущих шагах. Если нарисовать график изменения функции потерь - это будет выглядеть как неправильная парабола. В этом случае, после прохождения нижней точки параболы, модель начинает переобучаться и точность предсказаний для тестовых данных будет ухудшаться. В этом случае применяют `early stopping` - сравнивают среднее значения функции потери для последних N эпох - и если все N эпох это значение ухудшалось (росло), то обучение останавливают.

Comment: Это значение лосса я получил обучения на уже обученной модели. Предиктил по размеченным данным, чтобы увидеть лосс. В таком случае также не о чем не говорит?

Comment: @annaFerdsf, по-моему, считать “loss” для уже обученной модели смысла нет

Comment: А как правильно сделать? Посчитать accuracy?

Comment: @annaFerdsf, это зависит от того что именно вы хотите сделать правильно ;) Советую открыть новый вопрос...